# Content not visible in Android fragment

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Ps.: JSON data is not parsed in the `CardView`.

#### Main Fragment

I used a fragment for viewing the data on every item click and these are identified by slider menu. I wrote the code for parsing JSON data using Retrofit web service.

```java
public class Physical_Geography_Activity extends Fragment{
    View viewOne;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<QAModel> dataArray;
    private DataAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        viewOne=inflater.inflate(R.layout.geo_physical_layout,container,false);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)viewOne.findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(viewOne.getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadJSON();
        return viewOne;
    }
    private void loadJSON() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(),"Please wait","Loading..",true);
        dialog.show();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        Call<JSONResponse> call = requestInterface.getJSON();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                JSONResponse jsonResponse=response.body();
                dataArray = new ArrayList<QAModel>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getPhysiography()));
                adapter= new DataAdapter(dataArray);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Adapter

Custom `ListView` to view the data and wrote a holder class to hold the data, I used two `TextViews` to view the text, that is question and answer. The question and answer are dynamically changing whenever I am adding data in my remote server.

```java
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<QAModel> arrayList;
    public DataAdapter(ArrayList<QAModel> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.physical_card_layout,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.question.setText(arrayList.get(position).getQuestion());
        holder.answer.setText(arrayList.get(position).getAnswer());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView question,answer;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            question=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_question);
            answer=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_answer);


        }
    }
}
```

#### Model

Model has one constructor and two private string variables. And I have created the setters and getters methods for getting and setting the JSON data from the remote server.

```java
public class QAModel {
    private String Question;
    private String Answer;

    public QAModel(String question, String answer) {
        Question = question;
        Answer = answer;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return Question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        Question = question;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return Answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        Answer = answer;
    }
}
```

#### JSON Response

JSON Response class is written for getting the response of the model class with the method call.

```java
public class JSONResponse {
    private QAModel[] physiography;
    public QAModel[] getPhysiography()
    {
        return physiography;
    }
}
```

#### Interface

Interface has one method for getting the data from the server, that is `getJSON` and the interface does have the suffix url which hold the JSON data.

```java
public interface RequestInterface {
    @GET("bins/lo1md")
    Call<JSONResponse> getJSON();
}
```

Comment: are yo getting data in your adapter ?

Comment: try this "baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com/")" , i think you forget to put / at the end of base url .

Comment: I'm getting the count of cards, but not the text.

Comment: can you paste the json response in question ?

Comment: So what is the question? And why all text in **bold**?

Comment: I am getting empty cardview and all the cards are empty in the recyclerview.

Comment: @Lucifer please look at my code

Comment: @kdblue I tried forward slash / also at the end of the base URL, but im not getting output in my fragment

Comment: @NancyElisabeth Lucifer is asking for the response you are getting from the server. You can get this by putting a breakpoint after receiving a response or try this request in `postman`.

Comment: did you get response in JSONResponse jsonResponse=response.body() ??

Comment: @NancyElisabeth, Please check my answer

Comment: @Ranjan I am getting the JSON Response in the postman but the data is not parsed in the fragment

Comment: Yeah I saw the response. I'm working on the answer.

Comment: even you forget to "@SerializedName("key_parameter")" in model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a '/' in your base URL 'https://api.myjson.com'

Please update your line

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
```

to this

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://api.myjson.com/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
```

Also you need to change your model class to as below,

```
public class JSONResponse {

    @SerializedName("physiography")
    @Expose
    private List<Physiography> physiography = null;

    public List<Physiography> getPhysiography() {
        return physiography;
    }

    public void setPhysiography(List<Physiography> physiography) {
        this.physiography = physiography;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Physiography {

    @SerializedName("answer")
    @Expose
    private String answer;
    @SerializedName("question")
    @Expose
    private String question;

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not the issue, she is getting the count, just not the fields inside each `JSONObject`. I guess she needs to use `GSON`.

Comment: @Lucifer, I changed as you said, / is used in the end of baseURL but im not getting data into the fragment

Comment: @NancyElisabeth, ok, will it be possible for you to send me the code ?

Comment: @Lucifer, I will send to lucifer.stackoverflow@gmail.com, please check it and tell me the how to resolve it

Comment: @NancyElisabeth sure

Answer (score 0):

make `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

**Edited :**

```
public class JSONResponse {
 @SerializedName("physiography")
 public List<Physiography> physiography = new ArrayList<Physiography>;
}

public class Physiography {
 @SerializedName("answer")
 public String answer;
 @SerializedName("question")
 public String question;   
}
```

change your response class like then check it

Comment: even after giving adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); also, I am not getting parsed data in the fragment

Comment: did you get data in dataArray  object?

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't name your response object to something that common(`JSONResponse`). Name it more appropriately lets say `PhysiographyResponse`. Use `Moshi` library from squareup, it will generate JAVA objects of your `JSON` response.

Moshi dependency

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.5.0'
```

Data model classes -

```
import com.squareup.moshi.Json;

public class PhysiographyResponse {
    @Json(name = "physiography")
    List<QAModel> QAModel;

    public List<QAModel> getQAModel() {
        return QAModel;
    }

    public void setQAModel(List<QAModel> QAModel) {
        this.QAModel = QAModel;
    }
}
```

---

```
import com.squareup.moshi.Json;

public class QAModel {
    @Json(name = "answer")
    String answer;
    @Json(name = "question")
    String question;

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
}
```

Api interface

```
public interface RequestInterface {
    @GET("bins/lo1md")
    Call<PhysiographyResponse> getPhysiographyResponse();
}
```

Retrofit call

```
Call<PhysiographyResponse> call = requestInterface.getPhysiographyResponse();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PhysiographyResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PhysiographyResponse> call, Response<PhysiographyResponse> response) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                dataArray = new ArrayList<QAModel>(Arrays.asList(resposne.getQAModel));
                adapter= new DataAdapter(dataArray);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Boom !

1) put this gradle in your project .

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
```

2) make 2 models , 1st for

> QAModel

```
public class QAModel{
    @SerializedName("answer")
    private String Answer;
    @SerializedName("question")
    private String Question;

    public QAModel(String question, String answer) {
        Question = question;
        Answer = answer;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return Question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        Question = question;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return Answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        Answer = answer;
    }
}
```

and 2nd for Response of server

> ResponseQAModel

```
public class ResponseQAModel {
    @SerializedName("physiography")
    private List<QAModel> qaModels;

    public List<QAModel> getQaModels() {
        return qaModels;
    }

    public void setQaModels(List<QAModel> qaModels) {
        this.qaModels = qaModels;
    }
}
```

3)ApiClient where you setup your retrofit

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.myjson.com/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

4) Your Routes ApiInterface

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("/bins/lo1md")
    Call<ResponseQAModel> getJSON();
}
```

5)Now its time to catch output ;)

```
private void loadGSON() {
        final Call<ResponseQAModel> responseQAModelCall;
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        responseQAModelCall = apiService.getJSON();

        responseQAModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseQAModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseQAModel> call, Response<ResponseQAModel> response) {
                Log.d("kkkkk",response.body().getQaModels().toString());

                //responseQAMODELS contains all response pass to your adapter
                List<QAModel> responseQAModels = response.body().getQaModels();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseQAModel> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
```